# In Jira, how can I make "Log work hours" a mandatory field when I resolve an issue?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

When I in the agile board move an issue from "In Progress" to "Done", I want to be prompted to log how many hours I've worked on that issue.

Right now, I just get a message "CRM-123 was resolved". I want a modal/popup with mandatory "Log work hours" to appear.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to "JIRA Administration" -> "Fields" -> "Field Configurations"
2. Find your field configuration for your project and click "Configure" for it
3. Find "Log Work" and click "Required"

This will apply to all projects for this configuration. If you do not want other projects to be affected, then you should create a new field configuration.
(works for JIRA v6.3.13)

Answer (score 1):

In the workflow, on the Validator for this step, set "Time Spent" as a required field.

Comment: What is "the Validator"?